# Cases throwing unexpected when

Tags: case, vhdl, state-machine, fpga, xilinx

I'm making a statemachine in VHDL. My case is throwing an unexpected when error

```
case state IS
            --state 1 A
            WHEN s0=>
                --Half step
                if(FULL = '0' AND RIGHT = '1') then
                    state <= s1;
                else if (RIGHT = '0') then
                    state <= s7;
                end if;

                --Full step
                if (FULL = '1' AND RIGHT = '1') then
                    state <= s2;
                else if (RIGHT = '0') then
                    state <= s6;    
                end if;

            --State 2 A&B
            WHEN s1=>
                if(RIGHT = '0') then
                    state <= s0;
                else if (RIGHT = '1') then
                    state <= s2;
                end if;
```

However, when running a syntax check with xilinx ISE I'm greeted with a

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:164 Line 72. parse error, unexpected WHEN, expecting END
```

This happens 8 times in total. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` and `end if` are not balanced, so you will have to close the `if` with some more `end if`, or use `elsif` instead of `else if`.

You write:

```
if ... then
  ...
else if ... then
  ...
end if;
```

Even through your indentation shows this like balanced, it is not, since the right indentation would be:

```
if ... then
  ...
else 
  if ... then
    ...
  end if;
```

Then it is clear that the `if` and `end if` are not balance.

If you use `elsif` you can write it as:

```
if ... then
  ...
elsif ... then
  ...
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done the correction suggested by @MortenZdk, you need to also consider your logic.  In the following, you will never go to state s7 because the assignments done for full step will always over write it.

```
    WHEN s0=>
        --Half step
        if(FULL = '0' AND RIGHT = '1') then
            state <= s1;
        elsif (RIGHT = '0') then
            state <= s7;
        end if;

        --Full step
        if (FULL = '1' AND RIGHT = '1') then
            state <= s2;
        elsif (RIGHT = '0') then
            state <= s6;    
        end if;
```

For this example, I would recommend rewriting it as a nested if then else.  It is also a good practice to avoid the final elsif.

```
    WHEN s0=>
       if (FULL = '1') then  -- Full Step
          if (RIGHT = '1') then
            state <= s2;
          else 
            state <= s6;
          end if;

       else            --Half step   
          if (RIGHT = '1') then
            state <= s1;
          else 
            state <= s7;
          end if;
       end if;
```

I like the active high checks since with VHDL-2008 once your synthesis tool supports it, you will be able to leave off the "= '1'".  Ie:

```
   if FULL then  -- Full Step
      if RIGHT then
```

Alternately you could concatenate them into a variable and and use a case statement.  My suggestion is to always code for readability.